# Why does the transparency in my image become black, and how do I remove it?

Tags: python, pygame

I am loading a partially-transparent image into pygame and cropping it the following way:

```
img = pygame.image.load(image_url).convert_alpha()
cropped_img = pygame.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
cropped_img.blit(img, (0, 0))
```

The transparent sections of the image are seen as black. set_colorkey((0, 0, 0)) makes the black transparent, but it also makes the black in the image transparent. How would I only get rid of the transparency-caused black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

> ```py
> cropped_img = pygame.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
> ```

does not create a transparent image. `pygame.Surface((100, 100))` generates a completely black image. `convert_alpha()` does not change that. If you create a new surface and use `convert_alpha()`, the alpha channels are initially set to maximum. The initial value of the pixels is (0, 0, 0, 255)

If you want to crate a transparent image, you have 2 options. Either set a black color key with [`pygame.Surface.set_colorkey`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), before converting the foramt of the *Surface*:

```py
cropped_img = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
cropped_img.set_colorkey(0)
cropped_img = cropped_img.convert_alpha()
```

or use the [`SRCALPHA`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) flag to create a *Surface* with a per pixel alpha format.

```py
cropped_img = pygame.Surface((100, 100), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

Final code:

```py
img = pygame.image.load(image_url).convert_alpha()
cropped_img = pygame.Surface((100, 100), pygame.SRCALPHA)
cropped_img.blit(img, (0, 0))
```